# How to set MS Access Field Caption Property in C# with ADOX

Tags: c#, ms-access, adox

Can you please let me know how to set MS Access Field Caption Property in C# with ADOX?

I already tried this setting:

```
colFName.Properties["Caption"].Value = "First Name";
```

and

```
colFName.Properties["Jet OLEDB:Caption"].Value = "First Name";
```

but i am encountering with following error message:

---

### **ADODB.Properties**

### **Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.**

Thanks

Comment: You may wish to read: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=370657

Comment: You question asks about adox and c#. What do you want to do? Also, the caption property is of very little use outside of MS Access, so why c#?

Comment: I am treying to create a very simple database application and I would like to create some predefined tables in my database.Using ADOX I have done all part of the project but I have problem with "Caption" and "Required" properties to set! I easily set the Nullable and Description properties using above mention setting but I am getting the error on Caption and Requierd one